# Symfony2 setNormalizer with defined options

Tags: php, symfony, normalization, symfony-forms

I'm having a problem with Symfony options resolver where I need to specify a list of defined variables that should be normalized.

The problem is: I don't want to define all these variables again in

```
$resolver->setDefined();
```

because I have a list of defined fields in $builder and the same fields are defined in the entity SlotRequest.

Is there a different way of assigning all fields/variables from entity to resolver?

1. First approach:

> $resolver->setDefined([
>       'date_form','etc..'  ]);

But, it pointless because in the real world I have to normalize 10+ variables + 20 fields)

2. Second approach would be to parse all annotations from the entity 'SlotRequest', and then fill up an array with that object.

> $resolver->setDefined($anArrayOfParsedFieldsFromEntity);

Is there a better way of doing this?

An example of using:

In controller:

```
   $form = $this->createForm(new SlotRequestType(), new SlotRequest());
```

SlotRequestType:

```
class SlotRequestType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @var CCriteria
     */
    protected $resolved = null;

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date_from',null,['property_path'=>'dateFrom']);
           //more fields
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $this->resolved =  new \CCriteria();
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => SlotRequest::class,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'method' => 'GET'
        ));

         $resolver->setDefined([....]);// the list of fields

        $resolver->setNormalizer('date_from', function (Options $options, $value) {
            $dateFrom = new \DateTime($value);
            $this->resolved->setStartDate($dateFrom->getTimestamp());
            return $value;
        });
        //more normalizers
    }

    /**
     * @return null
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return CCriteria
     */
    public function getResolved()
    {
        return $this->resolved;
    }
```

Entity SlotRequest

```
<?php
namespace Test/Entity;

class SlotRequest
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Parameter [date_from] is missing.")
     * @Assert\Type(
     *     type="string",
     *     message="The value {{ value }} is not a valid {{ type }}."
     * )
    * @Assert\Date()
     */
    public $dateFrom;

    //more fields

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you do want to add an option per entity attribute to your form type? This looks like a horrible to use solution for a problem I yet don't get to me.

Comment: because that's how the normalizer works. Before normalizing I have to define options -> fields, otherwise I'm getting an exception '"The option \"date_from\" does not exist.' from "Symfony\\Component\\OptionsResolver\\Exception\\UndefinedOptionsException",

Comment: I meant why do you actually need a `date_from` option (and similar options for all your other attributes) in the first place?

Comment: probably, date_from is a bad example, but sometimes, option values need to be normalized before you can use them. In my case, I have some options that should be transformed into objects and parsed with different formats.

Comment: Looks like job for **Data Transformer** [read more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

Comment: Well, what I am concerned about it is that if you add options dynamically based on some class/object, you will end up with lots of options. How would cope with handling all of them properly? I am just trying to understand your use case to see if there isn't a much cleaner solution (as to be honest what you're trying to do sounds really weird).